# How to explain that the sum was calculated from the numbers contained in the list?

Tags: passive-voice

I mean, how to say that "contained in the list" relates to the numbers and not the sum.

When I write "The sum of the numbers are contained in the list." [Grammarly](https://app.grammarly.com/) corrects me and says that I must write "is"

Comment: I don't understand what you want to say, but *The **sums** of the numbers **are** contained in the List* is another valid construction. That's a valid *sentence*. For a *noun phrase*, you could use *The sum of the numbers **which** are contained in the List* (or *the **sums*** - both are fine).

Comment: @ColleenV Actually, I was looking at the title of the question. I understand your point.

Comment: @MickSharpe I also have gotten tripped up when there's a difference between the title and the body of the question. Titles often get edited to be more descriptive so a question will get more attention, so sometimes it gets out of sync.

Comment: You should give the whole sentence,  not a phrase to show what you want to say. For a phrase use "which" (see the first comment).

Comment: I want to say that in the list are stored numbers but not sum...

Answer (score 1):

Simplify, simplify, simply:

> The sum of the listed numbers is 149.
>
> The numbers listed sum to 149.

Answer (score 0):

I would just add *This is the sum of the numbers contained in the list* and the problem would be solved.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to say that in the list are stored numbers but not sum... –
>   Igor Bobko

This is the sum of the **numbers** which **are** contained in the list.

The number agreement of *numbers* and *are* (both are plural forms) makes clear that it is the numbers which are contained in the list, not the sum (a singular form).